# how to avoid this bug installing PHPMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, phpmyadmin

I recently upgraded my server from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, but the phpmyadmin version is still 4.5, while I want to install 4.6 (for support of the new JSON type).

The common instructions I find online is to add the repository `nijel/phpmyadmin` via apt-add-repository, but this gives me a strange bug.

```
root@myserver:~# add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
 Latest phpMyAdmin packages - https://www.phpmyadmin.net/. Based on packages available in Debian.

There are some notable changes:

* it currently requires updated PHP packages, you can get packages from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/
* it does include embedded copies of PHP libraries

If you like phpMyAdmin, you can support it's further development at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/donate/ or https://www.phpmyadmin.net/sponsors/, thanks!
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9zj2r1n2/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9zj2r1n2/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 06ED541C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp9zj2r1n2/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 06ED541C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Michal \xc4\x8ciha\xc5\x99" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 401, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 271, in add_ppa_signing_key
    tmp_export_keyring, signing_key_fingerprint, tmp_keyring_dir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 220, in _verify_fingerprint
    got_fingerprints = self._get_fingerprints(keyring, keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 212, in _get_fingerprints
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 695, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1059, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 96: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this looks like a bug in the ppa software, but I'm lost on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Apparently it's a system localisation problem. I ran

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and the ppa could be used without any problem.

Comment: Ah yes, should have realized that myself :D

Answer (score 1):

Try again?  It might be fixed since I get this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
 Latest phpMyAdmin packages - https://www.phpmyadmin.net/. Based on packages available in Debian.

There are some notable changes:

* it currently requires updated PHP packages, you can get packages from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/
* it does include embedded copies of PHP libraries

If you like phpMyAdmin, you can support it's further development at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/donate/ or https://www.phpmyadmin.net/sponsors/, thanks!
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpzsijcqvx/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpzsijcqvx/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 80E7349A06ED541C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Michal Čihař" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
OK
```

See the name? I get Čihař Where you got \xc4\x8ciha\xc5\x99. So it is an encoding/decoding problem of a none-ASCII character.

If it does not work report it on his launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin

Comment: No, still there. What version of add-apt-repository are you using? It feels like this a bug in the handler rather than in his code. If you're running a more recent version (e.g. in Ubuntu 16.10) it may already be fixed for you. Anyway, I'll let him know.

Comment: Some googling after your input helped me solve the problem, see other post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question, I added the PPA and ran it to see what would happen. In running it, I did receive a bunch of error messages. But then the Ubuntu software update popped-up by itself and I ran it. That updated `phpMyAdmin` to `4.6.5.2deb1+deb.cihar.com~xenial.3`

However, that resulted in the following warning: "*The secret passphrase in configuration (blowfish_secret) is too short.*"

To resolve that issue, you need to modify the file: /`var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php.`

```
 <?php
// $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'U0v9kMkdKICvsc6NYgfqryAu';
// modified 1/7/2017
// http://serverfault.com/questions/615550/phpmyadmin-error-the-configuration-file-now-needs-a-secret-passphrase
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'mrgQxxk8C-y}U7ji2BO9o5jLf}Qhe-BI[~6SUa';
```

phpMyAdmin now loads without any warning message.